# Maesh address not resolved in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I'm currently working with migrating a deployment to maesh. In this process I annotated, as required. my service with the maesh label. But trying to curl the service afterwards fails.

The old address(in my example) with http://world2.test.svc.cluster.local:30002 works fine.
But as soon as I try to ping the maesh adress http://world2.test.maesh:30002 it won't work.

For reference this is the deployment [Github](https://github.com/kek112/k8s-serviceMesh/blob/master/k8s-maesh/deployment/deployment.yml)

Further tests have shown that my configuration works locally with KinD. However, as soon as I'm working on Azure, the same configuration does not work.

It just says could not resolve host: world2.test.maesh with either curl or wget.

I'm not sure if I have just a small error or something.